# Flutter: app isn't properly install after building

Tags: android, flutter

I have created .apk file and tried to install it however without any success. There are no errors and looks like the installing process finished in 7.2 sec (according to the log). But the app is not opened in the connected device as usual. Perhaps, someone had the same issue. Thanks in advance for your reply.

This is the scenario of what I do:

```
mary@mary-X540LA:~/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp$ flutter build apk --debug
Initializing gradle...                                       1.5s
Resolving dependencies...                                    2.4s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...                               
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.

mary@mary-X540LA:~/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp$ flutter install
Initializing gradle...                                       8.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                   14.5s
Installing app.apk to SM G950F...
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                  7.2s
```

PS: when I simply run (or debug) main.dart, the process is stopped on the point of installing:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G950F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
```

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`? What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: Flutter clean did not help, I have done it, restarted, also tried "Invalidated Cashes/Restart" without any positive outcome.
My Flutter was a bit out-of-date so I have done "flutter upgrade" - now flutter doctor shows:

mary@mary-X540LA:~/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: This happens when it cannot install the apl on your device. Do you have the app installed with a second user? If so try to delete it.

Comment: UPDATES: guys, thanks for help. As of now the problem is not solved but at least I know what is the reason - the connected device is Samsung Galaxy S8. It has internal security features that blocked installation of an app that was previously uninstalled. I run app first time, it worked and then uninstalled it to try the flutter install command. But now neither Run, nor flutter install work. So now I try to find how to switch off that security features.
I have tried to run the app in the Emulator and yes, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways
But my problem was solved when I installed on another mobile device, and I realized it was due to device, not Android studio or flutter.
My simple way is to reboot the device and it will install normally